# Left ideals in Abstract Differential Geometry

Tags: differential-geometry

Im working with Malios (Abstract Differential Geometry).

Let $X$ be a top. space, with topology $\tau$ and $C^\infty(U\subset X,\mathbb{R})$ the algebra of all smooth functions from $U\subset X$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

He defined this object $A_{nd}(U\in \tau)$ to be this quotient of Algebras $C^\infty(U,\mathbb{R})/\ell_{nd}(U)$ where $\ell_{nd}(U)$ is said to be a left ideal.

If $X=\mathbb{R}^3$ with $\tau$ the standard topology, what are candidates for that left ideal?

Comment: $C^\infty(U,\mathbb{R})$ is a commutative algebra, so ideals are two-sided. The most obvious examples are the those smooth functions vanishing of all derivatives up to $k$-th order at a point $x\in U$. There are also others, such as $C^\infty_c(U)$.

Comment: What would be the resulting algebra if we do quotient out those algebras? Im trying to visualize these things and damn it's a bit hard. Also $\ell_{nd}$ is said to be "nowhere dense". Does this mean that it has some " structure" from the Integers?